# ElasticSeach - Sorting on dates

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index which I cannot setup every field with a mapping so dates are going in as strings...

Does anyone know how I would go about sorting on that string date?

I have looked at _script

```
{
    "query" : {
        ....
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "doc['field_name'].value",
            "type" : "string",
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails because its an analysed field...

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

If the format of the date is known, you can add that format to the dynamic_date_formats (Check out this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type/)) setting. When you index a new string field it will be converted to the date type which can be sorted in the normal way.

Example:

Create an index without properties:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/dates -d '
{
    "dates" : {
        "dynamic_date_formats" : ["yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"],
        "properties" : {
        }
    }
}'
```

Index 2 documents:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/dates/dates/1' -d '
{
    "arbitraryDate": "2013-01-01"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/dates/dates/2' -d '
{
    "arbitraryDate": "2012-01-01"
}'
```

If you check the mapping you will see that the field is not a string:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/dates/_mapping'
```

result:

```
{
  "dates": {
    "dates": {
      "properties": {
        "arbitraryDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can sort easily:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/dates/_search' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "arbitraryDate": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Your link is now outdated @moliware. Please replace it with the new elastic.co domain name: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elasticearch painless script like below;

```
{
    "size": "100",
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_script": {
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                    "source": "String dateAsString = doc['field_name'].value; String dateformat = 'yyyy-MM-ddZ'; DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateformat); return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateAsString, formatter).toInstant().toEpochMilli()"
                },
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```