# Dynamic mapping and nested sorting on dates in ElasticSearch/Java

Tags: java, sorting, datetime, elasticsearch, nested

I am new to Elastic Search. I am using Java, Elastic Search and Spring. My scenario is that I have a jQuery Table on a page. This table is a list of all the Users. Associated with users is a `Set` of extra information, we'll call this `extraDataValues`. This could be anything, the most important thing is that the value stored is a `String` value, which could be a formatted `Date` or `DateTime` String value. Here it is in JSON:

```
"extraDataValues": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "extraDataValueObject": {
            "id": 12,
            "label": "Metadata Date",
            "displayable": true
        },
        "value": "01/01/2015 00:01:11"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "extraDataValueObject": {
            "id": 13,
            "label": "Metadata TextBox",
            "displayable": true
        },
        "value": "zzzz"
    }
],
```

This brings me to the problem. Given that I have a nested `extraDataValues`set in Users with `extraDataObjects`, how can I:

- Perform a sort on a specific extraDataObject with either ID 12 or 13 that resides in extraDataValues. Basically, in Java I would get the `Set` of `extraDataValues` and within there I would search for all the `extraDataValueObjects` with ID 12, then I would see if that is a Date Time and sort it as a Date Time
- Perform a sort on a String value if it is a Date or Date Time?
- how can I dynamically change the mapping during runtime so I can perform such a dynamic sorting
- How can I do this in plain Elastic Search and how can I translate this to Java?

I can figure whether the value is going to be a `DateTime` or a `String' in Java but I have no idea how to translate this to Elastic Search in Java.

User object return from Elastic Search after a simple query:

```
User:
{
    "id": 1,
     "extraDataValues": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 10,
                "label": "Metadata Date",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "01/01/2015 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 11,
                "label": "Metadata TextBox",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "aaaa"
        }
    ],
    "username": "johnDoe",
    "firstName": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "fullName": "John Doe"

    "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Blogger",
        "active": true,
    },
    "club": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Photography",
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
     "extraDataValues": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 10,
                "label": "Metadata Date",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "01/01/2015 00:01:11"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 11,
                "label": "Metadata TextBox",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "zzzz"
        }
    ],
    "username": "marySmith",
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "surname": "Mary",
    "email": "mary@smith.com",
    "fullName": "Mary Smith"

    "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Moderator",
        "active": true,
    },
    "club": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Yoga",
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "extraDataValues": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 10,
                "label": "Metadata Date",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "02/02/2015 00:01:11"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "extraDataValueObject": {
                "id": 11,
                "label": "Metadata TextBox",
                "displayable": true
            },
            "value": "bbbb"
        }
    ],
    "username": "joeBloggs",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "surname": "Bloggs",
    "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
    "fullName": "Joe Bloggs"

    "type": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Admin",
        "active": true,
    },
    "club": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Cycling",
    }
}
```

User Mapping Document:

```
    {
    "User": {
       "properties": {
            "type": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index":    "not_analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw_lower_case": { 
                                "type":  "string",
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "fullName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },              
            "username": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "email": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "firstName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "surname": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":    "not_analyzed",
                "fields": {
                    "raw_lower_case": { 
                        "type":  "string",
                        "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "metadataFieldValues": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "metadataFieldDefinition": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "displayable": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index":    "not_analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw_lower_case": { 
                                "type":  "string",
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "club": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index":    "not_analyzed",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw_lower_case": { 
                                "type":  "string",
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },      
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:::

I took a look at these questions:
- [ElasticSeach - Sorting on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405195/elasticseach-sorting-on-dates)
- [Elasticsearch sort by single nested document key in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415494/elasticsearch-sort-by-single-nested-document-key-in-array)

Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A property must have the same type/mapping in all documents in Elasticsearch. You cannot change it later.

Once you index `extraDataValues.value` as a String it will remain a String and it must be a String in all documents.

That being said, maybe you could have a look at [script-based sorting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting). However, it seems that even in that case you cannot generate a script field of a new type.

You might have to consider a different modelling - index a date as a date type in an additional field.

By the way, there are other engines, such as [SIREn](http://siren.solutions) which let you have different types for the same property in different documents. *Disclaimer: I currently work for a company that develops SIREn.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for an answer. I checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415494/elasticsearch-sort-by-single-nested-document-key-in-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405195/elasticseach-sorting-on-dates. Do you think that is feasible for my scenario or am I heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: That would mean creating a normal date field if I understand correctly. That's what I suggested and it could probably be made to work.