# How to search only on the most recently inserted object (know by a date field) in an array of nested objects in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of objects in my elasticsearch index, like so:

```
{
  "group": "test_q",
  "artifact_type": "dashboard",
  "descriptions": [
    {
      "value": "original_description",
      "created_at": "2010-06-07T12:54:52Z",
      "created_by": "user_1"
    },
    {
      "value": "edited_description",
      "created_at": "2020-05-25T12:54:52Z",
      "created_by": "user_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Whenever the description is updated a new object is inserted in the descriptions array. On of my use case is to always query on the most recent description.

My idea was to sort the array on the created_date in descending order and pick the first one and query on that. 
But how do I do that. I am relatively new to elasticsearch and I can't seem to figure it out can someone help me with a sample query.

I am using elastic search version 5.6

Thanks in advance

Update:
Posting the field mappings as asked in comments:

```
  "properties": {
    "descriptions": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "created_by": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Update:
The only way I can think of right now is to add a "latest" boolean field to the nested object. But there has to be a better way.

Comment: Can you add the mappings of your fields

Comment: Elasticsearch does provide sort functionality based on date. This should help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405195/elasticseach-sorting-on-dates.

Answer (score 0):

It's [well established](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) that the `nested` type is

> best suited for data that does not change frequently

so I'd recommend to make your index description-based (on the top level) and not group-based.

---

With that being said, you can use a `script_field` to only return the latest descriptions like so:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "latest_desc": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
           def descriptions = params._source.descriptions;
           def sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
           def latest_obj = null;
           def latest_millis = 0;
           for (def desc : descriptions) {
             def iteration_millis = sf.parse(desc.created_at).getTime();
             if (iteration_millis > latest_millis) {
               latest_millis = iteration_millis;
               latest_obj = desc;
             }
           }

           return latest_obj
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then combine this w/ the global nested sort which will put the parent objects with the very latest timestamps to the top:

```
"query: {}, ...
"sort": [
    {
      "descriptions.created_at": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "descriptions"
      }
    }
  ],
"script_fields": {} ...
```

Comment: I still wouldn't be able to query on the latest description. Also seems like a lot of work. In SQL we can do it easily with a having clause, its surprising that elasticsearch doesn't support such a basic functionality.

I will probably go with the latest boolean flag approach

Thanks for you help though..!